# What is best way to implement Viewholder design pattern

Tags: android, gridview

These days I am more dealing with a custom `ListView` and custom `GridView`. I use the `ViewHolder` class for smooth scrolling. But there is something weird I have noticed. Items keep repeating when I scroll down the list or `gridView` when I implement `ViewHolder`, as it is recommended in Android guides. But when I initialize views out of it, items don't repeat.

Tell me how I can make this better. This gives me smooth scrolling without repeating the same items.

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    Main values;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public GridAdapter(Context context, Main main){
        this.context=context;
        this.values=main;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.getPosts().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageLoader imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView==null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,parent,false);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        viewHolder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(values.getPosts().get(position).getTitle()));
        imageLoader.displayImage(values.getPosts().get(position).getThumbnail_images().getFull().getUrl(), viewHolder.image);
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        public static ImageView image;
        public static TextView title;
    }
}
```

This code gives me repeating items and is the recommended way in Android guides:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
Main values;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public GridAdapter(Context context, Main main){
    this.context=context;
    this.values=main;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.getPosts().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageLoader imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView==null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,parent,false);
    viewHolder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    viewHolder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    
    viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(values.getPosts().get(position).getTitle()));
    imageLoader.displayImage(values.getPosts().get(position).getThumbnail_images().getFull().getUrl(), viewHolder.image);
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    public static ImageView image;
    public static TextView title;
}
}
```

Comment: private class ViewHolder{
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView title;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static ImageView image;
 public static TextView title;
```

is wrong. They should be

```
public ImageView image;
public TextView title;
```

without `static` . This should fix your issue. You can read more about static keyword [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: oh dear. I didn't even notice it. Thanks much!

Comment: Can you share your knowledge regarding static class? Why do we declare class static.

Comment: `static` applied to an inner class implies that the inner class doesn't see the outer environment. Applied to an object it means that you will have only one instance of that object that will be shared with all the instances of the classes that contain that object