# How can i add more than 100 images to my app

Tags: android-studio

I need to add more than 100 images to my app, 
the code is correct for many images but when I add more than 100 images, the app stops and shows me this error:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I tried to add this:

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

but I am getting the same error...

Comment: Are you displaying all images at once? What kind of layout are you using? Do you have different densities for each image? Are you using an image caching library? Would it be possible to fetch the images from a remote source in your app?

Comment: yes i'm presenting by GridView, using ConstraintLayout , yes different densities but not using an image caching library,No it is not remote source

Comment: please  any one help!!

Comment: What is the size of the images in bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that you are following the viewholder pattern. This makes sure that not all images are loaded at once, and the views in the grid are recycled. This should solve your problem.

Great example here:
[What is best way to implement Viewholder design pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941919/what-is-best-way-to-implement-viewholder-design-pattern)